# How to send user identification when a user interacts with an adaptive card in a Teams Message

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, adaptive-cards

We are using the graph API to send a message to the General channel of a Microsoft Team, which has a number of members.

We would like to allow any members to interact with the message via an adaptive card.

This is doable using say Action.OpenUrl or .Submit, however we need to know which user it is which is interacting. I imagine this must be a fairly common thing to do.

What solutions and options are available to do this?

For example, is it possible to obtain the user's Team id at the time an action is invoked ?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the details of your scenario? For example, what is the actual Adaptive Card? Are you using an open-URL action or a submit action? The difference between those is pretty important. What do you mean when you say "we need to know"? Are you saying you want the bot to receive information about the user, or do you want the information sent to some other endpoint? When a user clicks on a submit action an activity is sent to the bot. What's wrong with the identifying information that's in the activity?

Comment: The team is being made an offer of a work shift. Those who want to accept can press a button in the adaptive card which needs to update a record in a database associated with the user.   We could use either Action, but I think Submit would be a little more secure.  If there is no way for the adaptive card to infer the user id directly, then I assume a BOT will need to authenticate the user before continuing with the update.  Thanks for any suggestion on the best way to go about this.

Comment: Is your bot not receiving a user ID when a user clicks a submit action? Please edit your question to explain what you've tried so far and what's happening

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Still working on it, but have been temporarily diverted onto another project.  How does the user ID get passed to the BOT. Is this done automatically by Teams, or does the user need to be reauthenticated?

Comment: So I have a BOT running at an ngrok https URL.  I can obviously invoke the URL from a button in a teams message card - but it is not clear how to send the id of the user clicking to the BOT.   What is best practise here?

Answer (score 2):

Every activity sent to the bot has a `from` property that identifies the user that sent the activity. You can see the full activity schema [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference#activity-object). I advise you to run your bot in debug mode so that you can see all the data your bot receives. If you want to run your bot in debug mode and talk to the bot using Teams instead of Emulator, you can use tunneling: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-channel-ngrok